# Replacing a layout inside a Fragment in a ViewPager with a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm using a ViewPager with a Fragment for every page. Every page has a layout for the front and the back. If the fragment should have a back, **you would replace that with a Fragment**, but if I use:

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
    replace(R.id.layout_back,fragmentResultBack).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

it replaces all the layouts with the `id = R.id.layout_back` instead of just the one.

Comment: All the layouts ?? How many times In one fragment you are having id `layout_back`??

Comment: One in every fragment in the viewpager, but I found my problem. I used a static adapter.